# Rails only escape certain sections of content

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking to turn all words preceeded by a # (ie #stackoverflow) into a link that when clicked through will link to the search page with the word as a query.

I tried this recently and got the right HTML being returned, but because content is automatically escaped it showed as:

```
This is some content <a href="search?q=something">something</a>
```

My question is: Is there any way to only apply html_safe to every part of the content except for these links?

Comment: What sort of things will be in the text? Just text without any tags other than the `<a>`s that you want to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your tags are simple alphanumeric strings (i.e. nothing that needs to be HTML or URL encoded), then you could do something like this:

```
s = ERB::Util.html_escape(text_to_be_linkified).gsub(/#(\w+)/, '<a href="search?q=\1">\1</a>').html_safe
```

Then `s.html_safe?` will be true and `<%= ... %>` will pass the result through as-is. If you put this in a view helper, then you shouldn't need the `ERB::Util.` prefix on `html_escape`. If you do need to worry about URL or HTML encoding then you could modify the `gsub` replacement string appropriately.

For example:

```
> s = ERB::Util.html_escape('<pancakes & #things').gsub(/#(\w+)/, '<a href="search?q=\1">\1</a>').html_safe
> puts s.html_safe?
true
> puts s
&lt;pancakes &amp; <a href="search?q=things">things</a>
```